# How do I change the size of an image that is used for background?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I've been building a site that has two images above eachother. I've added the first one using the
background: url("../image") property.

The problem is that I don't know how to make it smaller, each time I change the width to a smaller amount, it looks like this
[IMAGE[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBlVK.png)

```css
li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.navigacka {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.logo {
    padding: 60px 0;
    text-align: center; 
}

.logo a {
    width: 260px;
    height: 344px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background:url("../img/logo.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    </head>

<body>
    <header id="header" class="navigation">
        <nav id="nav" class="mainnav">
            <div class="navigacka">
            <ul>
                <li>A PROPOS</li>
                <li>SERVICES</li>
                <li>IDEES</li>
                <li>CHEGUES CADEUX</li>
                <li>CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
            </div>

        <h1 class="logo">
            <a href="#">House Kitchen</a>
        </h1>
    
</body>
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `background-size:contain;` to your `.logo a` css.

This will do fit your photo to where it was.

```
.logo a {
    width: 260px;
    height: 344px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background:url("../img/logo.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set background property :
`background: url("../img/logo.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add `background-size: cover;` to make background image fit the screen  `background-position: center;` to make image position to center and  `height: 100vh;` to make the height fit the screen height